# Chaining named_scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question regarding working with named_scopes:

lets say i have the following model (i know some of the named_scope i've provided can be achieved directly through active record but they are just for the example):

```
def person

    named_scope :older_then, lambda {|min_age| {:conditions => ["age > ?",min_age]} }
    named_scope :by_first_name, lambda {|name| {:conditions => {:first_name => name}}}

    def self.some_function(age_param, name_param)
       chain = Person
       chain = chain.older_then(age_param) unless age_param.blank?
       chain = chain.by_first_name(name_param) unless name_param.blank?
       chain.all
    end
end
```

now lets say i want to call:

```
people = Person.some_function(20, "john")
```

while building the chain of named_scopes Rails will make 2 calls to the db:

```
select * from persons where age>20
select * from persons where age>20 and name='john'
```

obviously all I wanted was the result of the second query and didnt intended that the first query will be executed while building the chain of named_scopes. any ideas what i'm doing wrong here / whats the correct way to combine multiple named_scope by conditions?

BTW, i'm using Ruby 1.8.7 its old, i know... :(

Comment: Unless you're using an old version of Rails too, you should be using `scope`, not `named_scope`.

Comment: @meagar: The OP appears to be using Rails 2.x

Comment: Yap, using rails 2.3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
def self.some_function(age_param, name_param)
   chain = Person
```

to:

```
def self.some_function(age_param, name_param)
   chain = self
```

This will keep the original chain intact instead of starting a new one.

Comment: Ok, but will it solve the issue of the 2 SQL queries (instead of one) when chaining the 2 named_scope ?

Comment: it doesnt fix the issue, even when stating the chain with self instead of the model as you suggested, adding the 2 named_scopes to the chain, creates the 2 calls to the db, instead of just 1

Comment: MY BAD, it was only performing the 2 queries instead of 1 when i was debugging and i guess that the IDE performed those queries in order to evaluate the variables